# Java - Created a deck of cards, dealt five now need to determine whether the hand contains a pair

Tags: java, joptionpane, playing-cards

As the topic may explain, I need to figure out if out of the five cards dealt to the player are any of them considered a pair, If there is a pair it would be printed as part of the final JOptionPane to state "You have a pair of [pair]"
Is there a way to do this with the way i have the strings set up currently or will they not be recognized as pairs because they would never be the same suit...

thank you for any help.

here is my code right now:

```
       int cardsPerPlayer = 5;
   int players = 1;


      String[] suit = {" of Spades", " of Diamonds", " of Clubs", " of Hearts"};
      String[] face = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
      String [] deck = new String[52];

      for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++){
         deck [i] = face[i%13] + suit[i/13];
         //System.out.println(deck[i]);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i <deck.length; i++){
      int index = (int) (Math.random()*deck.length);

      String temp = deck[i];
      deck[i] = deck[index];
      deck[index] = temp;
      }
      for (String u: deck) {
      //System.out.println(deck);
   }
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           for (int i = 0; i < players * cardsPerPlayer; i++) {
            sb.append(deck[i])
            .append("\n");
        }
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: You should probably use Object oriented programming for this.

Comment: You should make `Suit` an `enum` type. You should make `Face` an `enum` type. You should make `Card` a class with two fields (`suit` and `face`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the most elegant solution, but this'll work:

```
//Create an array with an integer for all the different faces
int[] amount = new int[face.length];

//set all those values to 0
for(int i = 0; i < amount.length;i++) amount[i] = 0;

//loop through the five cards
for(int i = 0; i < cardsPerPlayer;i++) {

    //setting the faceIndex to 0, which will later be used to see what face it is (so if its a 2 it will have face 0, just like the array
    int faceIndex = 0;

    //looping through all the faces
    for(int j = 0; j < face.length;j++)  {

        //detecting if the jth item in the face array matches the first character of the current card
        if(face[j].equals(Character.toString(deck[i].charAt(0)))) {
            //make the faceIndex that number
            faceIndex = j;
        }
    }

    //so now faceIndex is the index of the face in the array
    //so if the face is 2, faceIndex is 0
    //if the face is K, the faceIndex is 11 etc.
    //we add one to that item in the amount array
    amount[faceIndex]++;
}
//now we know how much of each face is in the dealt cards
//looping through all the amounts of cards
for(int i = 0; i < amount.length; i++) {
    //if the amount of cards with the current face is 2, we have a pair! (which we print)
    if(amount[i] == 2) {
        System.out.println("You have a pair of " + face[i] + "s!");
    }
}
```

If you want to make a pair also include more than 2 of the same face, you shoukd change `if(i == 2) {` to `if(i >= 2) {`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. if you have time to explain to me why this works I'd greatly appreciate it, im still learning the basics of how coding works.

Comment: @Ahsifs better?

Comment: @Ahsifs I do agree with the comments that you should make a "card" class...

Comment: I will look into how to do that and attempt it shortly... currently the face[i] prints 4 no matter what the actual pair value is.